# Reading root node attribute with Wizous XML plugin in NSIS

Tags: xml, plugins, nsis

I am trying to read a root attribute, but still do not manage to do it using wizous xml.nsh plugin :(

Code itself is straight forward:

```
  ${xml::LoadFile} "${WHICH_DIR}" $0
  ${xml::RootElement} $R1 $R0
  !ifdef DEBUGMODE_NSISDBG
    nsisdbg::sendtolog /NOUNLOAD " root : $R1"
  !endif
  ${xml::GotoPath} "${XML_PATH}" $R1
  !ifdef DEBUGMODE_NSISDBG
    nsisdbg::sendtolog /NOUNLOAD "GotoPath '${XML_PATH}' result: $R1 "
  !endif
  ${xml::GetAttribute} "${XML_PARAM}" "${XML_VARIABLE}" $R1
  !ifdef DEBUGMODE_NSISDBG
    nsisdbg::sendtolog /NOUNLOAD "GetAttribute '${XML_PARAM}' result '$R1' : ${XML_VARIABLE} "
  ${xml::SetAttribute} "port" "$EditTextEditText" $0
  ${xml::SaveFile} "agent.xml" $0
  ${xml::Unload}
```

But the output still is not what I need:

```
<2012.04.17. 13:01:04>  root : agent
<2012.04.17. 13:01:04> GotoPath '/agent/' result: -1 
<2012.04.17. 13:01:04> GetAttribute 'port' result '0' :
```

The input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1257"?>
<agent port="0000" loglevel="3">
</agent>
```

**Thank you for any tip or kind of help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some preliminary points :

- as you did not provided a [sscc](http://sscce.org/) example, I needed to tweak your code a little
- it seems that you are not using the [NsisXml plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisXML_plug-in_%28by_Wizou%29) by Wizou but the [XML plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/XML_plug-in) by Instructor

While working on your sample I noticed that

- you might be confused between nsis constants and variables (you should look at the warnings that are outputed by the nsis compiler) as `GetAttribute` expects a variable as 2nd parameter to store the result
- `GotoPath` does not work with a final `/` I have the expected result by removing it
- I have changed the code as I do not use the nsisdbg plugin but only DebugView to catch `OutputDebugString` messages

```
!include "XML.nsh"

Name "Sample nsisXML"
OutFile "SampleSO.exe"

ShowInstDetails show    

!define XML_PATH "/agent"
!define XML_PARAM "port"
var XML_VARIABLE 

!define DEBUG `System::Call kernel32::OutputDebugString(ts)`

!macro GetXMLParam PATH PARAM VARIABLE
    ${xml::GotoPath} "${PATH}" $R1
    ${DEBUG} "GotoPath '${PATH}' result: $R1 "
    ${xml::GetAttribute} "${PARAM}" ${VARIABLE} $R1
    ${DEBUG} "GetAttribute '${PARAM}' result '$R1' : ${VARIABLE} "
!macroend

Section "Main program"

    ${xml::LoadFile} "so.xml" $0
    ${xml::RootElement} $R1 $R0
    ${DEBUG} " root : $R1"

    !insertmacro GetXMLParam "/agent" "port" $XML_VARIABLE
;        ${xml::GotoPath} "${XML_PATH}" $R1
;         ${DEBUG} "GotoPath '${XML_PATH}' result: $R1 "
;         ${xml::GetAttribute} "${XML_PARAM}" $XML_VARIABLE $R1
;         ${DEBUG} "GetAttribute '${XML_PARAM}' result '$R1' : $XML_VARIABLE "
    ${xml::SetAttribute} "port" "$XML_VARIABLE" $0
    ${xml::SaveFile} "agent.xml" $0
    ${xml::Unload}
SectionEnd
```

Result :

```
root : agent
GotoPath '/agent' result: 0 
GetAttribute 'port' result '0' : 0000
```

Comment: I am not confused - the other install scripts works fine when using such syntax. Only diff is that I am using them as I/O parameters for !macro to avoid need for addition variable/constant bloat in script... that is - your example with section is !macro with these 3 XML_*** as parameters... And, finally, your example still do not work. :(

Comment: @HX_unbanned: I am sorry but the code fragment that you provided just do not compile, so I did changed it to make it run, and it is not surprising if it not exactly what you have in your own code... Could you elaborate on "still do not work" ? Don't you have warnings in the compiler output ? I have edited my code to fix a typo from your original code to get a minimal working example.

Comment: now, if I change the `port` value from your sample xml to 42, I get the xml file agent.xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1257" ?>
<agent port="42" loglevel="3" />`

Comment: Hmm... it must be some kind of magic in my script :( ... Ok, try to put all this code into !macro ; then add the 3 params for the macro like this: !macro TheXMLMacro XML_PATH XML_PARAM XML_VARIABLE ... and then, form other .nsi script try to !insertmacro TheXMLMacro "/agent" "port" "$XML_VARIABLE" ... you should get empty $xml_variable, no matter what you do :(

Comment: Don't you have unexpected side effect with your macro ? I do not use often nsis macros directly myself, but for testing I have replaced several lines by a macro and the code is still working.

Comment: You may also have a scope conflict between the macro parameters and some global var ? Note that I have used some different names for the parameters inside the macro and the macro call.

Comment: Hmm ... ok ... at least some input ... Ill try to play with names ... though it is my last bet ... :(

Comment: Besides, I highly doubt that using !macro parameters and passing the values into the !macro defined in the !include "xyz.nsh" can make any kind of scope conflict as it is supposed to have such hierarchy for nsis installation script projects, isn't it? My macro is excatly as I posted in the question - I have not changed anything in the code, to be honest ... I thought it does not much matter ... especially because I can copile the script w/o problems ...